# Flash AS3 function trace same value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Could somebody possibly explain why the trace below returns the length of the array rather than the value of the "i" in the array item?

Many thanks, Nick

**AS3**

```
function createMarkers(mapLocations){
    var markerArray:Array = new Array();
    for(i=0; i<mapLocations.length; i++){
        markerArray.push(new marker());
        markerArray[i].x=mapLocations[i][1];
        markerArray[i].y=mapLocations[i][2];

        markerArray[i].markerText.text = mapLocations[i][0].toString();
        markerArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){clickTarget(e,i);});
        bgImage.addChild(markerArray[i]);
    }
}

function clickTarget(e:MouseEvent,a){
    trace(a);
}
```

Comment: Is `i` previously defined, or should this be `for (var i:Number = 0 ... )`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake when dealing with JavaScript/ActionScript functions. You're having the problem because functions are *closures*, which means they hold references to the variables defined in scope when the functions are defined.

This means that your anonymous handler function *closes* around the `i` variable, but it stores a reference to it, not its value. Since `i` changes, every function holds a reference to the same variable, which will just hold the last value assigned to it.

Basically, if you want to close around a variable's specific value, you have to *declare* the variable (using the `var` statement) within the function's scope. Because of that, this might look like it should work:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var scopedI:int = i;
    mc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (e:MouseEvent) { trace(scopedI); });
}
```

We declare a new variable, `scopedI`, within the loop's scope to close around that value specifically, since that variable will be redeclared every iteration of the loop with a unique value. Unfortunately, ActionScript, like JavaScript, does *not* have block-level scope, only function level scope, so all variable declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the function.

This pretty much just means that your `scopedI` type has the same scope as `i`, as well as any other variable declared inside that function. So, how can we create a new scope? With more functions. Keep in mind that in ActionScript, functions are objects, so we can do crazy things like this:

```
(function (id) {
    return function () { trace(id); };
})(7);
```

That bit of code creates a function, then immediately executes it with a value of `7` for the `id` parameter. This is useful, because now `id` is scoped to the inner function which we return, so that function will always print "7", no matter what happens externally.

Likewise, we can use this to scope our `i` variable in the loop. Your code could be updated to look like this:

```
function createMarkers(mapLocations){
    var markerArray:Array = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < mapLocations.length; i++){
        markerArray.push(new marker());
        markerArray[i].x = mapLocations[i][1];
        markerArray[i].y = mapLocations[i][2];

        markerArray[i].markerText.text = mapLocations[i][0].toString();
        markerArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, (function (scopedI) {
                return function (e:MouseEvent) { clickTarget(e, scopedI); };
            })(i));
        bgImage.addChild(markerArray[i]);
    }
}

function clickTarget(e:MouseEvent, a){
    trace(a);
}
```

Now, `scopedI` will be unique for each iteration. Yes, the syntax is a little bit messy, but this ends up being an extremely powerful and expressive feature of the language. If you can understand it, it's immensely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Alexis said,

Since you are adding a Click Event, I assume the item is a display object.

Unlike Javascript, you can also name the item & retrieve it back in the handler, something like :

```
        ...
        markerArray[i].name = "marker" + i; 
        markerArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickTarget);
        bgImage.addChild(markerArray[i]);
    }
}

function clickTarget(e:MouseEvent){
    var a = e.currentTarget.name.substr(6);
    trace(a);
}
```

Of course, also assuming the name attribute was useless for you until now.

Answer (score -1):

Because your inline mouse event is capturing the *variable* `i` (a reference) instead of its value.

Try this:

```
function createMarkers(mapLocations){
    var markerArray:Array = new Array();
    for(var i:Number = 0; i<mapLocations.length; i++){
        var thisI:Number = i;
        markerArray.push(new marker());
        markerArray[thisI].x=mapLocations[thisI][1];
        markerArray[thisI].y=mapLocations[thisI][2];

        markerArray[thisI].markerText.text = mapLocations[thisI][0].toString();
        markerArray[thisI].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
            function(e:MouseEvent){
                clickTarget(e,thisI);
            });
        bgImage.addChild(markerArray[thisI]);
    }
}
```

This should work because `thisI` is being recreated with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I don't think that will work due to hoisting, unless AS3 differs from JavaScript in a way that I'm unaware of.