# as3 event listeners in for loop to pass dynamic variable to function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need your help. I have an array with numbers, and I tried to pass a dynamic variable to a function in the mouse event listener. It works but not how I want. Whenever the mouse event listener is activated it passes the last value of that dynamic variable, not the value that was set. I tried to set this["n1"] and this["n2"] when passing to the function, but then the mouse event won't work (respond). How can I fix that? Here is my code:

```
var niz1:Array = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,4]];
var n,n1,n2;

for(n=0;n<3;n++){
    n1=niz1[n][0];
    n2=niz1[n][1];

    this["hovermc"+n1+"_"+n2].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(e:MouseEvent) : void {hover_effect_in(null,n1,n2,0,0);});
    this["hovermc"+n1+"_"+n2].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, function(e:MouseEvent) : void {hover_effect_out(null,n1,n2,0,0);});
}
function hover_effect_in(hovermc:MovieClip,h1:int,h2:int,h3:int,h4:int):void{
if(hovermc != null){
    hovermc.hoverbg.alpha=0.7;
}
if(h1 != 0 && h2 != 0 && h3 == 0 && h4 == 0){
    this["hovermc"+h1].hoverbg.alpha=0.7;
    this["hovermc"+h2].hoverbg.alpha=0.7;
}
}
function hover_effect_out(hovermc:MovieClip,h1:int,h2:int,h3:int,h4:int):void{
if(hovermc != null){
    hovermc.hoverbg.alpha=0;
}
if(h1 != 0 && h2 != 0 && h3 == 0 && h4 == 0){
    this["hovermc"+h1].hoverbg.alpha=0;
    this["hovermc"+h2].hoverbg.alpha=0;
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025783/flash-as3-function-trace-same-value this should help

Comment: would you mind uploading your fla and class somewhere ? maybe I could help more that way

Answer (score 0):

You are getting those values for n1 and n2 because those are the values of those variable at the time the event function executes even though it might be different at the time the function is defined with the addeventlistener command.

I can't think of a simple way to do what you want to do with your code, but a more practical way would be to have your listener call "hover_effect_in" directly, and then based on the calling mc's name, "e.target.name", apply your array values based on the mc's name. So if name=hovermc_1_2 then n1=1 and n2=2. So, based on a button name, you assign your values in the button handler.

Or, the sophisticated way to do is make a class for "hovermc" which has all your basic code but each class carries one set of your niz1 values and gets assigned to each of your button mcs.

Comment: I solved my problem in way I wanted, but your idea for taking value for n1,n2 from hovermc1_2 name is good. I will try that too. Thanks!